# Two if statements on same line

Tags: python

Very new to this, and cant seem to get these two to print on the same line. Python 3

```
 isCold= sys.argv[1] == 'True'

 isRainy= sys.argv[2] == 'True'

 if isCold:
   print "cold and",
 else:
   print "warm and ",

 if isRainy:
   print('rainy')
 else:
   print('dry')
```

Keep getting:

cold and

rainy

I need:

cold and rainy

Answer (score 1):

`print` has an `end` parameter whose default value is `\n`, a newline. Call the first prints with `print("cold and", end="")` and they won't skip to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

on the end of each print statement there is a \n which means "enter" or "new line"

build your str with + signs and print the build-up string at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Each call to `print` will result in the text being printed on its own line because a new line character is appended. This is [mentioned in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) -

```
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

The default value for `end` is why you are seeing a new line after each call to `print`.

---

What you could do is build a string variable in your conditional statements and then only print once at the end -

```
output = ''
 if isCold:
   output += "cold and"
 else:
   output += "warm and "

 if isRainy:
   output += 'rainy'
 else:
   output += 'dry'

print output
```

In addition, I see you are assigning string values instead of boolean values. In python `"True"` is not the same as `True`. You should assign proper boolean values. Take the following example -

```
myBool = 'True'
if myBool:
  print('Bool is truthy')

myBool = 'False'
if myBool:
  print('Bool is STILL truthy')

myBool = False
if myBool:
  print('This should not be printed')
```

Comment: Thank you this one seemed to work, except for my first isCold i needed to remove the + of the +=

Comment: @Chartrand - happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than two print calls, you can create a single string and print once.

Consider:

```
print("{} and {}".format(("warm", "cold")[isCold], ("dry", "rainy")[isRainy]))
```

In this case you are using the boolean value of each `iCold` and `isRainy` to index a tuple of strings to create a single string with all combinations.

You can also use the Python ternary to accomplish the same:

```
print("{} and {}".format("cold" if isCold else "warm", "rainy" if isRainy else "dry"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The print() function in Python takes more than one argument. One of the arguments is the `end`.

Now usually, the print function has a default argument of `end="\n"`, where `\n` is newline. This is the reason why your output comes as:
*cold and*
*rainy* - instead of:
*cold and rainy*

One solution to the many is to specify `end`. The `end` determines what the printed string will end with. For example:

```
>>> print("It is raining", end="!")

It is raining!

>>> print("What", end=",")

What,
```

So to get your output on the same line, you can try the following:

```
print("cold and", end="")
```

This will override the default argument of `'\n'` and you will get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
if isCold:
   a = "cold and "
else:
   b = "warm and "

if isRainy:
   print(a+'rainy')
else:
   print(b+'dry')
```

Comment: Hello, do you use discord?

Comment: Hey @BlackThunder, no I don't... Sorry

Answer (score -1):

Use a logical and:

```
if sys.argv[1] == 'True' and sys.argv[2] == 'True':
    print("cold and rainy)
```

Comment: `"True"`!= `True`

Comment: That's 'True' .